# Accessing Vuex module mutated state from a parent module

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm sending an `axios.post` with the whole `state` of my Vuex store which includes several `state`s from other modules. Inside one of these modules, there's an array which is being mutated as normal as `state.array` would mutate through dispatching that module's `actions`/`mutations`. Afterwards, I'm sending the axios request, but it sends `state` as if it wouldn't have been changed.

Here's the code:

**Parent module**:

```js
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
        // ... Modules
        person: person, // Includes all the state from person module
    },
    state: {
        // State
    },
    getters: {
        // ... Getters
    },
    actions: {
        // ... Actions
        update({commit, dispatch, state, rootState}) {
            axios.post(url, state) // Should send local state plus person's state
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        // ... Mutations
    },
}
```

**person module**

```js
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
        // ... Modules
    },
    state: {
        // ... State
        array: [1,2,3,4,5],
    },
    getters: {
        // ... Getters
    },
    actions: {
        // ... Actions
        addToArray({commit}, value){
            commit('addToArray', value)
        },
        deleteFromArray({commit}, value) {
            commit('deleteFromArray', value)
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        // ... Mutations
        addToArray(state, payload){
            state.array.push(payload)
        },
        deleteFromArray(state, payload) {
            // Initial state.array: [1,2,3,4,5], lenght: 5
            let arr = []
            for (let ar of state.array) {
                // Payload = 5
                if (ar !== payload) {
                    arr.push(ar)
                }
            }
            // New arr = [1,2,3,4]
            state.array = arr
            console.log(state.array)
            // Output: state.array: [1,2,3,4], length: 4
        },
    },
}
```

So initially this array has a length of 5, `deleteFromArray` decrement array's length down to 4 (everything working fine until here), then I update sending the `axios` request from the "Parent" module with the new mutated value of the array of length 4, but instead is sent with its initial value of length 5.

On the other hand, `addToArray` works well, and it also sends the new array value of length 6 as it's expected.

I can't really see what is happening here. I've also tried a different way of removing from the array with `splice()`, and it works in the local state, but mutation doesn't seem to be caught from the "Parent" module, again, only on array subtraction.

Comment: For deletion, what about this oneline code instead? 
`state.array = state.array.filter(item => item !== payload)`

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You don't use `update` anywhere, while it's obviously the first place to check

Comment: @Kunukn thanks, looking good for less code

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry, I tried to reduce the code a lot because is really extensive, and I obviously not include the part which calls the `update` action, but I'm indeed calling it, but to make it simple is just a button inside a Vue component that just dispatch `update` action.

Comment: MCVE is a requirement for code-related questions on SO. The problem you describe isn't something that is widely known and can be guessed at once. There shouldn't be a difference in a way `push` and `splice` are treated by Vue reactivity. It's unknown at which point you call deleteFromArray and update. The most simple explanation is that you have race condition. In order to determine this, there should be a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1. Is there a code example for this? `Afterwards, I'm sending the axios request` 2. I don't see `rootState` being used. 3. Could you try with rootGetters instead?